# KendoUI grid server filtering not getting data to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have implemented kendo UI Grid in my MVC project with jquery. I want to perform server filtering, but I am not getting filter object into my controller. I have tried below code.

JS Code:

```
$("#AccountLedgerReport").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: ["excel", "pdf"],
        excel: {
            allPages: true,
            filterable: true
        },
        pdf: {
            filterable: true
        },
        dataSource: {
            type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
            serverSorting: true,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: getActionURL() + "url?site....,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            pageSize: 50,
            schema: {                    
                    return data;
                },
                data: 'data',
                total: 'total',
                model: {
                    fields: {                        
                        PnrNumber: { type: "string" }
                        , TransactionId: { type: "number" }
                        , CreatedByName: { type: "string" }
                        ...
                    }
                },
            },
            aggregate: [
                { field: "xxx", aggregate: "max" }                    
            ]
        },
        dataBound: onDataBound, 
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        filterable: {
            mode: "row"
        },    
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5,
            serverFiltering: true,
            pageSizes: 50
        }, 
        columns: [
        {
            field: "x",
            title: "x",
            format: x,
            width: 145,
            footerTemplate: 'Total :',
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    showOperators: true
                }
            },

        },...
        ]
    });
```

Then my controller side where i want to get data is :

```
public JsonResult actionname(int site..., IDictionary<string, string>[] sort, .., IDictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, string>[]> filter)
```

Here the challenge i am facing is filter parameter. Sorting's data is coming when they are needed but filter's is not coming.

The Requesting URL Being is as below:

```
https://localhost/...?site..&sort[0][field]=xx&sort[0][dir]=asc
```

This is when sorting is done.

```
https://localhost/..?site...&filter[logic]=and&filter[filters][0][operator]=eq&filter[filters][0][value]=held&filter[filters][0][field]=xxx
```

This is when the filter is in process.

I am not getting where i am doing wrong.

Comment: What happens if you change the controllers signature to `([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)`.  The parameters for sorting, paging, grouping, etc... should be found in the `request` fields.  I also use POST for all my kendo dataSource requests, but you seem to show parameters on the URL, which would be get parameters -- That could be part of the issue.

Comment: Actually for that i think i have to add kendo's dll and another stuff ... which i want to avoid .... is that i can do without dll than please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few parameters left in the Action method as per official document detail, so please update your controller action with the following. Unfortunately, I had this issue before and resolved on my end. In this way sorting and filter will work perfectly. Please try this approach.

> JS Code

```
$("#AccountLedgerReport").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: ["excel", "pdf"],
        excel: {
            allPages: true,
            filterable: true
        },
        pdf: {
            filterable: true
        },
        dataSource: {
            type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
            serverSorting: true,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: getActionURL() + "url?site....,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            pageSize: 50,
            schema: {                    
                    return data;
                },
                data: 'data',
                total: 'total',
                model: {
                    fields: {                        
                        PnrNumber: { type: "string" }
                        , TransactionId: { type: "number" }
                        , CreatedByName: { type: "string" }
                        ...
                    }
                },
            },
            aggregate: [
                { field: "xxx", aggregate: "max" }                    
            ]
        },
        dataBound: onDataBound, 
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        filterable: {
            mode: "row"
        },    
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5,
            serverFiltering: true,
            pageSizes: 50
        }, 
        columns: [
        {
            field: "x",
            title: "x",
            format: x,
            width: 145,
            footerTemplate: 'Total :',
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    showOperators: true
                }
            },

        },...
        ]
    });
```

> Action Controller

```
public JsonResult YourActionName(int id, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int take, int skip, int page, IDictionary<string, string>[] sort, int dateFilterOn, string number)
```

Comment: Wow...!! how did you find it? This is working. Thank you so much Ankit, you save my all time. Now that's work perfectly as expected. You're a savior.